# vector.size() returns 1 even though there are more than 1 elements in it?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am new to vectors in C++, my goal is to read a line from file store it in a string vector, transform it to integers and push it to an int vector. I came across the problem that when I transform char to int I loose leading 0s. I want to retain the leading 0s (The file is a matrix file). I am storing the final file in a 2D int vector. When I run temp.size() I get the result as 1, I know this is something to do with how I converted the string to integers and so I believe there is only 1 number being stored in the vector.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
std::vector< std::vector<int> > res;
std::ifstream f("input.txt", ios::binary);
string line;
int count;
while(std::getline(f,line))
{
  std::vector<string> line_data;
  std::vector<int> temp;
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::string value;
  while(iss >> value)
    {   

        line_data.push_back(value);
        std::transform(line_data.begin(), line_data.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(temp),
                    [](std::string &s) {    return std::stoi(s); } );

    count = value.length();

    count = count - temp.size(); // temp.size() returns 1, why is that and how can I fix it?
        cout << count <<endl;
        temp.insert(temp.begin(),count,0);
  data.push_back(temp);

}
```

My input is a Boolean square matrix of unknown length. say for example :

```
00101
10101
10100
00101
01111
```

EDIT:

when getting an output from int vector data:

```
101
10101
10100
101
1111
```

lost leading 0s

so I tried to calculate the difference in lengths of value and temp and insert the 0's manually.

Comment: Your input lines only contain one item. The `while(iss >> value)` loop only has one iteration for each line, so `line_data` and `temp` both have size 1. What did you expect to happen? If you are still having trouble please post a MCVE along with the exact input and output and explain how the output differs from what you expected.

Comment: You cannot retain leading 0s with an integer - an integer is a number.  But, if you know how many characters you want to print, you could always prepend a bunch of 0s in the print before your integer value.

Comment: @M.M stoi is likely to discard leading 0s no? Its converting 1 string to 1 integer not each character in the string which is what i think OP is trying to do?

Comment: "I want to retain the leading 0s..."

Comment: @M.M my output is missing 0s and I want to insert the 0's is there a way I can calculate the number of 0s to add, or do I need to go another way ?

Comment: @Borgleader I tried atoi as well, same result.. I dont want to iterate and convert the characters, as it will take longer for larger files.

Comment: Should I just iterate characters and convert ?

Comment: If you know how many characters were read in before the conversion (per line), and you know how many characters are supposed to print, It seems a simple subtraction should get the number of leading 0s.  Then just print those in front of your converted number.

Comment: @Borgleader I was responding to the question "temp.size() returns 1, why is that and how can I fix it?", which has nothing to do with leading zeroes. It seems OP has two separate issues

Comment: Question - will the size of your matrix change - what is the max size it can support?

Comment: Doesn't matter, but the code is easier if the size of each line is less than the number of bits in an unsigned integer.  Basically, you can create an array of unsigned integers - 1 per line and set the value of each bit to 0 or 1 depending on data.  Ignore then extra unused bits at the end of each int.  Now you basically have a packed array of booleans.

Comment: the matrix can be of any size, but it is a binary square matrix. max size is determined by the matrix in the input.txt file

Comment: @MichaelDorgan do you mean, read the file as characters and push a 1 or 0 into the int vector ?

Comment: Roughly.  Instead of storing integers, store a bitfield array instead.  It's a closer representation of your data anyway.  Hell, you may already being doing this with your 2D array.  It's hard to say from description.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan dont you need to define the size of the bitfield array during compilation ? if so I dont want to do that, to save space.

Comment: You need to define the size of your square bool somewhere.  It's 1 value - probably an int.  Unless this thing is going to be gigabytes in size, your saving space argument here is not really valid.  Get it working first, then worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using binary mode for text data? Simplified it a little bit, so it comes to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("input.txt");
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
    std::string line;

    // fill data
    while (std::getline(f, line))
    {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(),
            std::back_inserter(temp),
            [](char c) {  return std::stoi(std::string(&c, 1)); });

        data.push_back(temp);
    }

    // print data
    for (std::vector<int> x : data)
    {
        for (int y : x)
            std::cout << y;

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
00101
10101
10100
00101
01111
```